# Mobile Internet for Raspberry PI (IRL Streaming Backpack)

Tags: networking, streaming

I currently thought about making an IRL Streaming Backpack just for fun and I think I have everything together now except the Mobile connection Part. The Backpack will work like follows:

- I have a Backpack with a Raspberry PI and a Webcam attached to it.
- The Raspberry Pi will be streaming this Webcam Footage to an RTMP Server hosted in my Home where I have stable Internet
- The Pi will be connected with 1 or more internet connections (probably more because Internet here in Germany is more than bad lol)

**Now my question:**
How would I connect the Pi to the Internet?

- Would I just need to create a Hotspot on my Phone? (I have an unlimited Flat and Medium coverage)
- Would I need to get like one or two Mobile USB "Routers" and put in a new SIM Card with new Flats (Oh, its gonna be expensive xD)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, but your question is far to broad. We cannot give a complete tutorial how to manage network and internet connections with a Raspberry Pi. Please have a look at [Get started with Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/) and try its solutions, in particular shown in section "*configuration*". If you get stuck with one of it, then please ask about its details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- WiFi Hotspot, USB or Bluetooth tethering to a mobile.
- USB mobile broadband stick directly connected to the Raspberry Pi.
- An external mobile hotspot router.

All of abowe is feasible solutions.